# How can I reset field on React-Select?

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

I have a one React Select element. The options come from backend and this is an example. And it is like this

My department options

```
[
    {
        "departmentId": null,
        "parentDepartmentId": 1,
        "subDepartmentId": null,
        "parentDepartmentName": "Dep",
        "departmentName": null,
        "subDepartmentName": null
    },
    {
        "departmentId": null,
        "parentDepartmentId": 4,
        "subDepartmentId": null,
        "parentDepartmentName": "department1",
        "departmentName": null,
        "subDepartmentName": null
    }
]
```

Parent element

```
  const [structureTypes, setStructureTypes] = useState({
    departmentId: '',
  });

  const handleChangeDepartmentId = useCallback((selectedOption) => {
    setStructureTypes((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      departmentId: selectedOption.parentDepartmentId,
    }));
  }, []);

    <SimpleSelectComponent
          name="departmentId"
          title="Department"
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.parentDepartmentName}
          getOptionValue={(option) => option?.parentDepartmentId}
          options={departments}
          onChange={handleChangeDepartmentId}
        />
```

Child element

```
import Select from 'react-select';

const SimpleSelectComponent = ({ title, getOptionLabel, getOptionValue, options, onChange}) => {
    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>{title}</label>
        <Select
          getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
          getOptionValue={getOptionValue}
          options={options}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

export default SimpleSelectComponent;
```

The problem is that I have a reset button and If the user clicks this button, the field has to reset. The state works, it reset but the input value does not reset. It stays the last label.

My function

```
  const handleReset = () => {
    setStructureTypes({
      departmentId: '',
    });
  };
```

I tried several variants, but none of them don't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleReset = () => {
  setStructureTypes({
    departmentId: '',
  });
  
  handleChangeDepartmentId(null); //this will reset the selected value
};
```

Let me know, If the issue still persist.

Comment: Your method did not work. I get an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentDepartmentId')